# Всё(,) что только можно

Tags: запятые

Как правильно?

`Я сделал всё что только можно.`

`Я сделал всё, что только можно.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я сделал **все что можно.***  Устойчивое сочетание.

*Я сделал все, **что только можно**.* Сложноподчиненное предложение.

**Вопрос № 303815.** В предложении: "Мы — лишь крохотный осколок силы, которая способна на все что только можно и нельзя вообразить." нужна ли запятая после "все" и перед "что"? На каком основании, если да?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Запятая перед что **нужна**. Она ставится между частями сложноподчиненного предложения.